# Multiple DbGeography classes exists, which one is correct?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, spatial

There's 2 `DbGeography` classes with these namespaces:

```
System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography    (Entity Framework)
System.Data.Spatial.DbGeograph            (.Net Framework)
```

which one should I use?

Comment: Which version of EF are you using? I believe the namespaces got changed in EF 6.

Comment: @Peter I'm using EF 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using EF 6, then `System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography` is the correct one to use. You should also remove any assembly references to `System.Data.Entity.dll`.

A lot of things got moved from the `System.Data` namespace to the `System.Data.Entity` namespace (and moved from the System.Data.Entity.dll to EntityFramework.dll) in EF6.